# Custom UI Editor flakiness

Tags: excel, ribbonx, vba

I have been using the above tool and Excel 2013 with mixed success. The good news is that it eventually works, the bad being that when it doesn't the following horrible things  happen when modifications inside of the Editor are made:

1. modules with callback code revert to their state before the callbacks were added (ie, the code is lost!). This seems to happen even when there are no errors. *This* is frustrating!
2. custom tabs and context menus just don't show up if there is a conflict. For example specifying a callback to getLabel in xaml when there is also a label attribute specified. Of course this is my bad but it wouldn't hurt if the tool would catch this for me.

**Question**
Is the Editor the state of the art for customizing the ribbon and adding context menus. I realize the price is right but would gladly pay for a smoother and more reliable dev experience

Comment: `I realize the price is right` Price? Ain't it free?

Comment: You could use VSTO (VB.Net/C#) if price is not a constraint

Comment: @SiddharthRout. Ain't free always the right price?? At least not considering you usually get what you pay for... [yes, it's free!]

Comment: lol... You had me confused for a moment..

Comment: The CustomUI editor doesn't affect modules in the workbook - but if you do make changes to the workbook while it's opened in the UI editor, then yse you may lose changes. Also, you can set Excel to warn you of UI errors.

Comment: @Rory. Yeah, that was the problem. If you want to make that an answer I will give it to you as it might save someone else some grief. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CustomUI editor doesn't affect modules in the workbook - but if you do make changes to the workbook while it's opened in the UI editor, then yes you may lose changes.

Also, you can set Excel to warn you of UI errors which will at least assist you in working out why your tabs/controls aren't appearing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem Rory described (losing your changes) has bitten me many times, even when I am fully aware of why it happens (I may just forget I made changes externally).

Due to that and many other limitations I saw in the Custom UI Editor, I decided to create my own editor based on the original:

https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

For this particular issue, what I did was to implement a "reload on save" feature, which reloads the entire contents of an Office file (spreadsheets, VBA modules, etc.) right before the custom UI files are saved, hence preventing any accidental loss. I hope you might find this useful to prevent any future frustration!

***Disclaimer: I am (obviously) the author of the tool above***